# How to check if element exists inside numeric array in Twig?

Tags: arrays, json, twig

Say we have an array inside a variable (let's call it `arr`) in Twig that looks like this:

```
foo: [
{
    title: 'foo',
    id: 1
},
{
    title: 'bar',
    id: 2
}],
bar: [
{
    some: 23,
    required: true
},
{
    some: 12,
    required: false
}]
```

The amount and order of array elements can difer so I won't be able to use something like arr.foo[0] to get the first element. How would I be able to create a Twig conditional `if 'bar' exists in the foo array OR 'some' equals to 12 in my bar array`?

I tried:

```
if 'bar' exists in arr.foo.title or 12 exists in arr.bar.some
```

(this doesn't work obviously because the keys of foo and bar are numeric and not 'title' or 'some').

I also tried:

```
if arr.foo.title['bar'] is defined or arr.bar.some['12'] is defined
```

(it's not defined due to the same reason)

And I tried:

```
for item in arr.foo if item.title == 'bar' or for item2 in arr.bar if item2.some == 23
```

(doesn't work because of two `for` loops)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is JSON not an array. Both PHP and Twig arrays must have unique named keys.

This is what the Twig code should look like for a valid array:

```
{% set arr = {
    'foo1': {
        'title': 'foo','id': 1
    },
    'foo2': {
         'title': 'bar','id': 2
    },
    'bar1': {
         'some': 23,'required': true
    },
    'bar2':{
         'some': 12,'required': false
    }
} %}
```

I created an array similar to what you have above.
Then here is a TwigFiddle that you can see how you might run a Test: https://twigfiddle.com/8ydz3t

You can play around in Twigfiddle to see how you might use Twig and the array to figure out what you need.

I hope that helps!